# Logging data values through Vb.Net to Excel with real time

Tags: vb.net, excel, logging

I've encountered difficulties on logging all the data values in text box from excel file. I just want to know how to log the data in different cells in excel?? Its like a monitoring system that I need to do. And can somebody help me on how I will log the values with date and time in excel? Thanks :)

here is my sample code :

```
    Dim OpenExcelFile As String =("C:\Users\RoseAnnMarey\Documents\TRYMUNA.xlsx")
    Dim oExcel As Object
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.workbooks.open(OpenExcelFile)

    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    oBook = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook
    oSheet = oExcel.worksheets(1)

    ' update the value

    oSheet.Range("c5:c15").Value = TextBox1.Text
    oSheet.Range("d5:d15").Value = TextBox2.Text
    oSheet.Range("b5:b15").Value = Label4.Text

    'save
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
    oBook.SaveAs(OpenExcelFile, 51) '51 == xlsx
    oBook.Close()
    oBook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The first you need to do is write down step by step what you want to do.  For example, place value of TextBox1 in location XYZ and specify what XYZ is.  Is it a specific cell location or is it the next row in a column of values.  No one is going to be able to help you if you can not state what your goal is other than ` I just want to know how to log the data in different cells in excel?? Its like a monitoring system that I need to do.`  What part do you not know how to do?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to code the logging of the data values came from one textbox to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

To format the cell as a date you would use:

oSheet.Range("c5:c15").NumberFormat = ""mm/dd/yyyy"

You can modify the format string to be whatever date format you need.

You can also reference the specific cell by using to set the value:
oSheet.Cells(row, column).Value